# Asyncio two parallel func

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have two func:
This:

```
async def alarm_logic() -> None:
    alarm_time = get_alarm_time()
    choise_sound = set_alarm_sound(get_alarm_sounds())
    while alarm_time != get_current_time():
        print(get_current_time())
        time.sleep(0.5)
    play_alarm_sound(choise_sound)
```

and this:

```
async def math_asking() -> None:
    random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(random_number)
    while True:
        input_choise = input('Число от 1 до 10: ->')
        if input_choise == random_number:
            return False
    sys.exit()
```

How i can do this work parallel, when alarm playing sound?

I try smthg like this:

```
ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [ioloop.create_task(alarm_logic())]
wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)
ioloop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)
ioloop.close()
```

but it doesnt work how i want.

```
ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [ioloop.create_task(alarm_logic())]
wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)
ioloop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)
ioloop.close()
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! The [tour] and [ask] are good places to start. Also, look at what makes a good [MRE]: "doesn't work how I want" is not clear. What output are you getting, and what output do you want?

Comment: Asyncio won’t help you here. You’ll be better off using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.

Comment: The problem with the code is that it is not asynchronous, e.g. `input` is blocking function.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with AsyncIO because you are not using asynchronous operations. There is no `await` keyword in both of your functions, which indicates that no asynchronous operation occur. You should either employ multithreading or convert your program to be asynchronous.

If you take the first path, use the threading Python library and if you are the second one, use `await asyncio.sleep(0.5)` instead of the synchronous `time.sleep(0.5)` and convert `input()` to be async (search the web for something like "python asyncio read standard input").